# Error Cuda when combine Makefile YOLOV4 on google colab?

Tags: makefile, google-colaboratory, yolo, darknet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM8rr.png)

I met " include/darknet.h:664:5: error: ‘cudnnTensorDescriptor_t’ does not name a type" error when train yolov4 on google colab.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ej84fB-pMzcxgTEPBqr4y790v3wH9UfE?usp=sharing

Please, don't forget to change the `compute_capability` according to your GPU

Then, select your preferred settings for the following:

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=1
CUDNN_HALF=0
OPENCV=1
AVX=0
OPENMP=0
LIBSO=1
ZED_CAMERA=0
ZED_CAMERA_v2_8=0
```

You can refer to this to explore your options: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-compile-on-linux-using-make

Reference for the colab lines:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mzL6WyY9BRx4xX476eQdhKDnd_eixBlG#scrollTo=GNVU7eu9CQj3